# Wordpress rewrite rule involving index.php doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Before I start, I'd like to say that I did search for topics similar to my problem and tried all solutions provided, but my problem still persists, so I had to post my own question.

Anyway, inside our wordpress site, we have a page called site.com/shops and we want to put a parameter to it. After that we want to use a rewrite rule so that site.com/tx will load site.com/?pagename=shops&state=tx. We put this on our .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^tx(/)?$ index.php?pagename=shops&state=tx[L]
```

For some reason this doesn't work like we intended. I checked to see if index.php was the problem by changing it to

```
RewriteRule ^tx(/)?$ test.php?pagename=shops&state=tx[L]
```

That worked, so I believe the problem is that it doesn't work if index.php was used. How do I make it work using index.php? TIA.

Comment: Could anyone help me please? :(

Comment: Anyone? Please?

Answer (score 0):

Replace .htaccess code with below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress_test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress_test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i hope it's works

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work, and it also gave me an internal server error.

Comment: can you change rewriteRule path?

Comment: I did. The directory is in the root though so / isn't really needed to be changed. Still the code didn't work.